# Windows Phone doesn't support this file type.What can I do?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing Windows Phone 7 application with C#.Application have to download torrent files.So it's extension ".torrent".But Windows Phone doesn't support torrent files.So it says "Can't download file.Windows Phone doesn't support this file type." What can I do ?

Comment: How are you trying to download it, to start with? And where are you seeing that message?

Comment: monotorrent? https://github.com/mono/monotorrent

Comment: I am trying with web brower (internet explorer).I use WebBrowserTask.So I am seeing on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to add handler for custom extensions in Windows Phone 7. According to rumors based on the leaked SDK, it may be possible in Windows Phone 8 (but no official announcement yet). So for now, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks,but I'm sad.Because this application would be port of my Android application.

Comment: It is possible, but not through the browser. Look at the HttpWebRequest and related classes. More information can also be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998903/download-files-in-wp7